# Get a certain line with beautifulsoup and inserting it in the loop again

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Im using beautifulsoup and im getting the url with the tag ('a').

Now my problem is, I cant figure out how to get a certain line.

I let the user input a certain line `position` and how many times the loop should run `countrepeat`. This will be implemented in the code.

So I cant figure out two things:

1. How do I only get `position` line (for example 3rd).
2. How do I implement that URL into the loop again so it follows that link

My code im using:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter - ')
countrepeat = int(input("Enter repeat number:"))
position = int(input("Enter start position:"))

for i in range(countrepeat):
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    tags = soup('a')
    print(tags.get('href'))
    url = tags.get('href')
```

Comment: Please clarify: Are you trying to get the `position`th href in the soup? You want it to ask for `url` for each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Yes the positionth href in the soup, but it should only ask for the url the first time. Then it should automatically follow the link it found in the href. 

Thats why I put url = tags.get('href') at the bottom, that way I thought it would put the URL that was found in the variable url.

Comment: I tried to get the positionth href in the soup by implementing the following: tags = soup('a',[position]) but that doesnt work, I get a traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `position` is 0-indexed, use `soup.findAll('a')[position]` to get the `position`th anchor in the soup.

To get the href of the anchor, use `soup.findAll('a')[position]['href']`.

To have the loop use this href for the next request, update `url` in the loop to the href from the anchor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, tried what you proposed, but I still get a traceback on the same line with the 'href'

Code:

    for i in range(countrepeat):
        html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        tags = soup('a')
        url = tags.findAll('a')[position]['href']
        print(url)

Traceback:

    "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key

Comment: that looks messy, can you tell me how I can implement a code block in a comment?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your code. I should have used `soup` instead of `tags`. I have updated my answer accordingly. `tags = soup('a')` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Great comments, Erfan please leave feedback if it worked as you said. Check his reply with an ANSWER so that the future users may find use in it too.